# How can I graph datagridview's columns values using filters?

Tags: filter, datagridview

I would like to graph the values of a column of a datagridview (I can do it, all the values of the column are graphed) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSTAs.jpg)

But it doesn't works for me, I want to graph by projects using filters without showing the results of another project. is this possible?
I'm using Visual Studio 2017.
Regards!